# trying to filter a link using jquery. dont know how to put filter() into use here

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to just get 'whatsapp'

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=" +
"ploads/2022/08/Offer-Image-Intro-647-x-742-E.jpg&quote=
```

can someone help?

I know the concept of split() and filter(), but don't know to use the to only select whatsapp

this is my piecd of code:

```
jQuery('div.share_block > div > a').click(function(){
var _shareLink =jQuery(this).attr('href').filter() === "whatsapp";
var visit_link= jQuery(this).prevUntil('div.offer_hover_block > a').text();
  
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'whatsapp_click',
      'carouselHref' : _shareLink,
      'pageName' : visit_link
    });
  });
```

EDITED:
I just want to filter out whatsapp. my code above has a var shareLink which prints out the whole whatsapp link. i want to add a function to just filter out whatsapp

Comment: To get just `'whatsapp'`, use `'whatsapp'` string, wrapped in single or double quotes or backticks, and do not use any links, split's and filter's. If you mean something else, please clarify your question, preferably showing input (the link, I guess), expected output (`'whatsapp'`?), explanation if needed and your attempt with run results (actual output).

Comment: @SUTerliakov, this is the link: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=" +
"ploads/2022/08/Offer-Image-Intro-647-x-742-E.jpg&quote=

I just want to filter out whatsapp. my code above has a var shareLink which prints out the whole whatsapp link. i want to add a function to just filter out whatsapp

Comment: Put another way: you want to check if an `<a>`'s href contains "whatsapp" (just in the site, or also in the path?)

Comment: Given that you know how to use `.split` you can use: 
 `if (jQuery(this).attr('href').split(".whatsapp.").length > 1) ... then it's a whatsapp link`  - ofc this will find it anywhere in the href, not just the site.   Various ways to get just the site (ideally using a URI object), one option: `(jQuery(this).attr('href').split("?")[0].split(".whatsapp.").length > 1`

Comment: @freedomn-m yes I just did it usinf splice(). thanks anyways:)
I updated the answer on stackoverflow myself, dont know why it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it appears you are trying to test if `whatsapp` string is part of the URL. Consider the following.

```
jQuery('div.share_block > div > a').click(function(){
  var _shareLink = (jQuery(this).attr('href').indexOf("whatsapp") > -1);
  var visit_link = jQuery(this).prevUntil('div.offer_hover_block > a').text();
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'whatsapp_click',
    'carouselHref' : _shareLink,
    'pageName' : visit_link
  });
});
```

> The `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

See More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

If you have a URL like:

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=ploads/2022/08/Offer-Image-Intro-647-x-742-E.jpg&quote=
```

And an expression like:

```
var _shareLink = jQuery(this).attr('href').indexOf("whatsapp");
```

The value of `_shareLink` will be:

```
12
```

You can then use this as a logical statement to get `true` or `false`.